# How to catch $() error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

Ok so I want to make a simple "web scraping" app;

I have this simple code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/example',
    success: function(data) {
        var elements = $(data)   //<--error here        
    } 
});

<h1>the html does not matter</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ='error.js'></script>
```

This works, I get the elements, however, I will be running this up to 100000 times and there is this error that pops up and makes debugging a pain.

```
GET file:///images/side-rail-slot-4-chosen-min.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The error comes about in the $(data) call.

I have tried:

```
$(data).error(function(e){/*do nothig*/})
$(data).on('error',function(e){/*do nothig*/})
```

And I have even gone into the jquery file to try and insert a try-catch ....somewhere. but the error persists.

Comment: add error handler to the ajax call..

Comment: U can also do try { } catch() in JS if needed.

Comment: @Andrew try catch is not going to work with Asynchronous calls

Comment: I am sorry I didn't explain where the error was coming from. its not from the $.ajax is from the $(data). 

the I can't add a try catch to it because it is Asynchronous

Comment: Why can't you put `try`/`catch` inside of your success callback? `try { var elements = $(data); } catch(e) { /* do nothing */}`

Comment: @mhodges, it's an asynchronous call so I don't get to do that.

Comment: @Doopdon I'm confused. Neither the success callback, nor the jQuery wrapper function are asynchronous

Comment: @Doopdon Asynchronous setTimeout with callback function containing try/catch [works here](https://repl.it/@ugam44/ConsiderableSurprisedAttribute). (should be throwing an error in the console because foo is undefined, but it is caught by `catch` and ignored)

Comment: well, the function may not be, but it's triggering something that is, and that is what is causing the error. It is like its trying to actually render the HTML but it is unable to find assets listed in it. In this case the (side-rail-slot-4-chosen-min.png). So it throws out the error. I can still get the elements in it. I just don't want to see ten thousand errors.

Comment: @Doopdon Without a reproducible error condition, I'm afraid this question may be off-topic.

Comment: @mhodges if you take that script and copy paste it into a local file and run it. (I added the HTML) you will get the error.

Comment: @Doopdon I posted an answer - take a look and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

you need to set an error handler, just like the success handler:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/example',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    var elements = $(data)           
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  } 
});
```

here is an implementation i found on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/AGpP5/

**Edit (additions from the comments by @mhodges):**

The error callback will only be called for HTTP status code of `400` or higher. Several error conditions can happen that will not be caught by the error.

Comment: Just a note on this: the `error` callback will only be called for HTTP status code of 400 or higher. Several error conditions *can* happen that will not be caught by the `error` callback.

Comment: yes, this is of course true. Errors which come with a `200` need to be checked inside the `success` handler

Comment: I have an error handler in the $.ajax call, it rarely gets used, it's not the source of the error. I have edited my post to make that more clear.

Comment: @Doopdon there is no error handler in your example. If `GET file:///images/side-rail-slot-4-chosen-min.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` appears after executing the script "10000" times seems to be caused by connection issues. `404` means "not found". Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @messerbill I'm thinking we are on different pages. the error is not with the $.ajax, that is working well. when I try to parse the HTML I get an error. I still get what I want. but I get a slew of errors. I'm trying to get it up and running in jsbin right now so give me a second.

Comment: @messerbill I cannot get my code to run on jsbin or jsfiddle. only locally. they really don't like $.ajax()

Comment: @Doopdon so publish the "not working" jsfiddle here in a comment and i will have a look on it to make it running (but this may take a moment, i have to do some stuff now)

Comment: Html `<h1>the html does not matter</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ='error.js'></script>`



  Js `$.ajax({ url: 'http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/example',
    success: function(data) {
        var elements = $(data)   //<--error here        
    } 
});`  copy paste that, look in the console, and you shoudl see it. I appologize I can't seem to format this better.

Comment: why did u not just post the fiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be

```
<div class="spanish_ad center">
  <a href="http://spanish.yourdictionary.com/">
    <img src="/images/side-rail-slot-4-chosen-min.png" width="300" height="250" nopin="nopin">
  </a>
</div>
```

All other images are prefixed with `http://cf.ydcdn.net/latest/`, so I tried prepending that to the URL and it worked just fine.

It may feel a bit hacky, but you can do a string replace on that text, like so:

```
var newData = data.replace('src="/images/', 'src="http://cf.ydcdn.net/latest/images/');
var elements = $(newData);
```

Comment: I suppose that works just fine thank you. It does indeed feel hacky but it only needs to run a few dozen times. I just need to see through the errors to get the info I need.